# Headers designing in extarticle class (with babel)

Tags: babel, ukrainian

I use:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section*{The name of one of the section without numbering}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{The name of one of the section without numbering}
\section{Long title of one of the section in several lines in Ukrainian with numbering in the table of contents}
\subsection{Subsection name}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection name}
\end{document}
```

and obtain:

1st page:

[image]

2nd page:

[image]

I would like:

for 1st page:

1.a) Center the title of the table of contents;

1.b) Add a dot after section (subsection and subsubsection) numbering.

for 2nd page:

2.a) Remove the numbering of the second section, but saving it for links and formula numbering;

2.b) Center the header of the second section;

2.c) Manual line break for the sections heading without numbering;

2.d) Add a dot after subsection and subsubsection numbering;

to obtain something like that (for 2nd page):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should meet all your requirements. For the manual line break in section heading you need write the optional section heading which be typed in the table of contents, and put some manual line breaks in the mandatory argument which will be typed in the document.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\centering\contentsname}{}{}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\csname the#1\endcsname.}{}{}
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\patchcmd{\@sect}{#6}{\ifstrequal{#1}{section}{\centering#6}{#6}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}}{\@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\ifstrequal{#1}{section}{Розділ~\thesection}{\@svsec}}\ifstrequal{#1}{section}{\par\nopagebreak}{}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section*{The name of one of the section without numbering}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{The name of one of the section without numbering}
\section[Long title of one of the section in several lines in Ukrainian with numbering in the table of contents]{Long title of one\\ of the\\ section in several lines in Ukrainian with numbering in the table of contents}
\subsection{Subsection name}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection name}
\section{Long title of one of the section in several lines in Ukrainian with numbering in the table of contents}
\subsection{Subsection name}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection name}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's completely what I needed, Thanks!